# Deleting from a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm creating a method that takes in a grade (a100, q68, etc), removes that grade from a 2D array, and resizes the array. The first letter of the grade determines the row that the grade is in, and the rest is the grade. The method returns true if the grade was deleted and false otherwise. Here's my code so far. I know I'm missing something, but I'm not sure what it is.

```
public boolean deleteGrade(String newGradeIn) {

  char row = newGradeIn.charAt(0);
  double grade = Double.parseDouble(newGradeIn.substring(1));
  int index = categoryRow(row);
  if (index == -1) {
     return false;
  }

  double[] oldArr = gradeTable[index];
  double[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, oldArr.length - 1);
  newArr[newArr.length + 1] = grade;
  gradeTable[index] = newArr;


  return true; 
}
```

Comment: What is your actual problem / question?

Comment: I think I'm leaving out something that actually deletes the grade.

Comment: You think you left it out or is you code actually failing at deleting an item? You should maybe read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: `newArr[newArr.length + 1] = grade;` is never going to work.  You cannot set an element outside of the bounds of an array.

Comment: It's not deleting the item. Sorry, I'm new to this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your logic of removing from array is not right.
Replace the below code

```
double[] oldArr = gradeTable[index];
double[] newArr = Arrays.copyOf(oldArr, oldArr.length - 1);
newArr[newArr.length + 1] = grade;
gradeTable[index] = newArr;
```

with the following one

```
    double[] oldArr = gradeTable[index];
    double[] newArr = new double[oldArr.length - 1];
    int i = 0;
    for (double element : oldArr)
    {
        if (element != grade)
        {
            newArr[i++] = element;
        }
    }
    gradeTable[index] = newArr;
```

Here we will iterate through all the elements to find the actual grade and remove it.
Note: Scenario in which given gradeIn is not present, is not considered.